# Problem with long chapter title and arsclassica

Tags: classicthesis

I have a problem with arscalssica style in combination with classicthesis.

The text under the chapter title starts always at the same position, independently on how long is the chapter title, which produce this ugly behaviour:
[image]

The code I used to generete this output is really basic:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{\blindtext}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The compilation raises the following warnings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrreprt.cls: Class scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `tablecaptionabove'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\classicthesis\classicthesis.sty: Class scrreprt Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together(scrreprt)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty: Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty: Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty: Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty: Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty: Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\classicthesis\classicthesis.sty:373: Package scrreprt Warning: Activating an ugly workaround for a missing(scrreprt)                feature of package `titlesec` on input line 373.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arsclassica\arsclassica.sty:192: Package hyperref Warning: Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used,(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 192.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arsclassica\arsclassica.sty:192: Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' has already been used,(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 192
```

The behaviour is ok if I do not use arsclassica but only classicthesis:
[image]

Comment: Very good example.

Comment: `\chapter{\blindtext}` -- Do you mean this seriously? ;-)

Comment: It is just an example, but it should work anyway. In my thesis I have quite long chapters titles, not so long of course, but three lines yes :-D

Comment: If you are interested, we have been chatting a bit about it http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20070403#20070403

Comment: `\renewcommand{\formatchapter}{\raggedright}`

Comment: As far as I remember, the documentation of `arsclassica` tells you that long chapter titles are not supported.

Comment: Imho, if you can't keep your chapter titles on one line you shouldn't use the style. It looks odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try redefining the command `\formatchapter` in this way:

```
\renewcommand\formatchapter[1]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ }%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax}%
    \raggedright\spacedallcaps{#1}%
    \end{minipage}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\renewcommand\formatchapter[1]{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ }%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax}%
    \raggedright\spacedallcaps{#1}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{\blindtext}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]