# in my thesi this is the result, why?

Tags: thesis

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                      % corpo del font principale
               a4paper,%                   % carta A4
               twoside,openright,%         % fronte-retro
%              oneside,openany,%           % solo fronte
               titlepage,%                 % frontespizio
               headinclude,,footinclude,%  % testatina e piede di pagina
               BCOR5mm,%                   % rilegatura di 5 mm
               cleardoublepage=empty,%     % pagine vuote senza testatina e piede di pagina
               tablecaptionabove,%         % didascalie in cima alle tabelle
               ]{scrreprt}                 % classe report di KOMA-Script;

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                   % codifica dei font:
                                           % NOTA BENE! richiede una distribuzione *completa* di LaTeX,
                                           % per esempio TeXLive o MiKTeX *complete*

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                % codifica di input; anche [latin1] va bene
                                           % NOTA BENE! va accordata con le preferenze dell'editor

%\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}        % per scrivere in italiano e in inglese;
                                           % l'ultima lingua (l'italiano) risulta predefinita
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}         % frontespizo
                                           % per includerlo nel documento bisogna:
                                           % 1. compilare una prima volta Tesi.tex;
                                           % 2. compilare a parte Tesi-frn.tex, generato dalla compilazione precedente;
                                           % 3. compilare ancora Tesi.tex. 

\usepackage{indentfirst}                   % rientra il primo capoverso di ogni sezione

\usepackage{graphicx}                      % immagini

\usepackage{listings}                      % codici

\usepackage[font=small]{quoting}           % citazioni

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}        % matematica

\usepackage[italian]{varioref}             % riferimenti completi della pagina

\usepackage{mparhack,fixltx2e,relsize}     % finezze tipografiche

\usepackage{tabularx}                      % tabelle di larghezza prefissata

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,backref,square,natbib,backend=biber]{biblatex}
                                           % eccellente pacchetto per la bibliografia;
                                           % produce uno stile di citazione autore-anno; 
                                           % lo stile "numeric-comp" produce riferimenti numerici;
                                           % NOTA BENE! bisogna che il proprio editor sia configurato per biber

\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}          % database di biblatex 

\usepackage{subfig}                        % sottofigure, sottotabelle

\usepackage{lipsum}                        % testo fittizio

\usepackage{eurosym}                       % simbolo dell'euro

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%          % numeri dei capitoli nel font Euler
            subfig,%                       % se si usa il pacchetto subfig
            beramono,%                     % Bera Mono come font a spaziatura fissa
            eulermath,%                    % AMS Euler come font per la matematica
            pdfspacing,%                   % migliora il riempimento di riga
            listings,%                     % codici
%           parts,%                        % da decommentare in un documento diviso in parti
            ]{classicthesis}               % stile ClassicThesis

\usepackage{arsclassica}                   % modifica alcuni aspetti di ClassicThesis

\usepackage{bookmark}                      % segnalibri

\input{impostazioni-tesi}                  % file con le impostazioni personali



\begin{document}




\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
%******************************************************************
% Materiale iniziale
%******************************************************************
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Frontespizio}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Colophon}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Dedica}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Indici}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Sommario+Abstract}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Ringraziamenti}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Introduzione}
\cleardoublepage
%******************************************************************
% Materiale principale
%******************************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Capitoli/Lorem}
\input{Capitoli/Ipsum}
\input{Capitoli/Commento}
\input{Capitoli/Rapporto}
\appendix
\input{Capitoli/Dolor}
% *****************************************************************
% Materiale finale
%******************************************************************
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Bibliografia}
\input{MaterialeInizialeFinale/Dichiarazione}
\end{document}
```

the result:

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228220/problem-with-long-chapter-title-and-arsclassica, well, possible duplicate even.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe that you'll find your answer in the linked thread.